# Error en procedimiento MySql sin sentido

Tags: mysql

Me encuntro nuevamente en un error que no tiene sentido
Tengo el siguiente procedimiento!

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `estado`(
    IN `_estadoactual` varchar(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE terminalid INT(11);
SET terminalid = IFNULL(obteneridterminal(), -1);
INSERT INTO terminales_estado (estado) SELECT _estadoactual FROM DUAL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM terminales_estado a WHERE a.estado=_estadoactual) = 0;
IF (terminalid = -1) THEN
INSERT INTO terminales (conexionactual, estado) SELECT  USER(), a.id FROM terminales_estado a WHERE a.estado = _estadoactual;
ELSEIF (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM terminales_estado a WHERE a.estado = _estadoactual) =1 then
UPDATE terminales a INNER JOIN terminales_estado b ON a.estado = _estadoactual SET a.estado = b.id WHERE a.id = terminalid;
END IF;
END
```

Con las siguientes tablas
**Terminales**

```
CREATE TABLE `terminales` (
    `cajaindependiente` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `computerid` VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `conexionactual` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `empleadoactual` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `estado` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `grupo` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `imprimirticket` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `nombredeimpresora` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `nombrepc` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `computerid` (`computerid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_terminales_terminales_estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_terminales_terminales_estado` FOREIGN KEY (`estado`) REFERENCES `nuevo`.`terminales_estado` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=15
;
```

y tambien **Terminales_estado**

```
CREATE TABLE `terminales_estado` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `estado` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `estado` (`estado`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12
;
```

Inserto el siguiente registro:

```
INSERT INTO terminales_estado (estado) VALUES ('caja');
INSERT INTO terminales(conexionactual,estado) VALUES (USER(),(SELECT id FROM terminales_estado WHERE estado='caja'));
```

Y al dar la siguiente consulta:

```
CALL estado('caja');
```

ME da el siguiente error y no le encuentro sentido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor alguien sabe que puede ser? porque no hay ningun valor double en ninguna parte como para que de este error!! desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿No te falta el `_` aquí para `estadoactual`, al final de la instrucción: `INSERT INTO terminales (conexionactual, estado) SELECT  USER(), a.id FROM terminales_estado a WHERE a.estado = estadoactual;`?

Comment: lo corregi, aun asi el error sigue siendo el mismo

Comment: OK, revisa este `JOIN` y los que sean similares: `ON a.estado = _estadoactual`, la columna `estado` es de tipo `INT`, mientras que `_estadoactual` es `VARCHAR`, no puedes hacer `JOIN` entre datos de tipo dispar.

Comment: puede ser por comparar un integer con un string https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63112) ( al parecer ambos se convierten a double )

Comment: btw la traducción del error podría ser "mas mejor" onda "truncado erróneo de valor DOUBLE"  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Creo que malbarez tiene razon, en inner join:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `estado`(
    IN `_estadoactual` varchar(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE terminalid INT(11);
SET terminalid = IFNULL(obteneridterminal(), -1);   
INSERT INTO terminales_estado (estado) SELECT _estadoactual FROM DUAL WHERE (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM terminales_estado a WHERE a.estado=_estadoactual) = 0;
IF (terminalid = -1) THEN
INSERT INTO terminales (conexionactual, estado) SELECT  USER(), a.id FROM terminales_estado a WHERE a.estado = _estadoactual;
ELSE
UPDATE terminales SET estado = (SELECT id FROM terminales_estado WHERE estado = _estadoactual) WHERE id = terminalid;
/*UPDATE terminales a INNER JOIN terminales_estado b ON a.estado = _estadoactual SET a.estado = b.id WHERE a.id = terminalid;*/
END IF;
END
```

La solucion seria esta! muchas gracias